# Process fork isn't executing desired code

Tags: c, exec, fork

So I'm trying to execute this code given to me by my professor. It's dead simple. It forks, checks to see if the forking works properly, then executes another bit of code in a separate file.

For some reason, on my OS X 10.9.5 machine, it's failing to execute the second bit of code. Here are both of the programs:

exercise.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>


int main() {
  pid_t child = fork();
  if ((int)child < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "fork error!\n");
    exit(0);
  } else if ((int)child > 0) {
    int status;
    (void) waitpid(child, &status, 0);
    if (WIFEXITED(status)) {
      printf("child %d exited normally and returned %d\n",
         child, WEXITSTATUS(status));
    } else if (WIFSIGNALED(status)) {
      printf("\nchild %d was killed by signal number %d and %s leave a core dump\n",
         child, WTERMSIG(status), (WCOREDUMP(status) ? "did" : "didn't"));
    } else {
      printf("child %d is dead and I don't know why!\n", child);
    }
  } else {
    char *argv[] = { "./getcode" };
    execve(argv[0], argv, NULL);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

And getcode.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main() {
  int rc = 256;
  printf("I am child process %d\n", getpid());
  while ((rc > 255) || (rc < 0)) {
    printf("please type an integer from 0 to 255: ");
    scanf("%d", &rc);
  }
  exit(rc);
}
```

I compile both with the commands:

```
gcc -Wall -pedantic-errors exercise.c -o exercise
```

and

```
gcc -Wall -pedantic-errors getcode.c -o getcode
```

Unfortunately, the only thing I get back from the child process is a return code of 0

```
./exercise
child 903 exited normally and returned 0
```

I'm baffled. Can anyone help?

EDIT: Okay, so I included `perror("execve")` as requested, and it returns `execve: Bad address`. So how can I fix that?

EDIT2: All right. I fixed it. I've changed the bit of the above code to include this:

```
char *argv[] = { "./getcode",NULL };
execve(argv[0], argv, NULL);
```

Null termination fixes the argv issues.

Comment: `char *argv[] = { "./getcode", NULL };`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to terminate argv with a NULL element. From the execve man page:

```
Both argv and envp must be terminated by a NULL pointer.
```

Also it is not clear that NULL is valid for the envp argument. The Linux man page says

> On Linux, argv can be specified as NULL, which has the same effect as specifying this argument as a pointer to a list containing a single NULL pointer. Do not take advantage of this misfeature! It is nonstandard and nonportable: on most other UNIX systems doing this will result in an error (EFAULT).

Possibly specifying envp as NULL is similarly nonstandard. Use execv not execve if you don't need to specify an environment.

You should check the return value of execve. And use errno to determine the cause. Eg., use `perror("execve")` It may be complaining.

Comment: Okay, sorry for my confusion, after terminating argv with a null pointer, it's working! Thank you for your help. I would have tried that sooner, but it actually worked initially, then stopped working after a few edits. Thanks again!

Comment: Cool. Those data dependent bugs with unspecified behavior are nasty.

Answer (score 1):

You're not checking the result of the `execve` call, so I suspect it's failing, and the child process is reaching the `return 0` at the end of `main`.